# ASP.NET runtime error : Ambiguous Match found

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, web-applications, asp.net-2.0

Recently, my team converted ASP.NET project from .NET 1.1 to .NET 2.0. Everything is pretty good so far except for one web page.

This is the error message I got when I tried to open this page:

> ### Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Parser Error  Description: An error
>   occurred during the parsing of a
>   resource required to service this
>   request. Please review the following
>   specific parse error details and
>   modify your source file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Ambiguous match
>   found.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 1:  <%@ Control Language="c#"
>   AutoEventWireup="false"
>   Codebehind="Template.ascx.cs"
>   Inherits="eReq.Web.WebControls.Template.Template"
>   TargetSchema="http://schemas.microsoft.com/intellisense/ie5"
>   %> Line 2:   Line 3: 
>   function
>   ExpandCollapse_Template(inBtn,
>   inSection, inSectionID) {
>
> Source File:
>   /WebControls/Template/Template.ascx
>   Line: 1
>
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Version Information: Microsoft .NET
>   Framework Version:2.0.50727.3053;
>   ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3053

I tried renaming class and renaming filename but it didn't work.

Anyone have any idea on this?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It may appeared because of different names of components? for example Button1 and button1, it compiles as casesensitive, but executed as caseinsensitive.

Comment: The project compiled without any problem.
Running this web app froom any other pages are fine except this page.
I believe this is a runtime error.
In Visual Studio 2008, there is a blue underline under the directive line in the Template.ascx file saying "ASP.NET runtime error : Ambiguous match found."

Comment: I found it at last... Thanks x2.
There's a user control that use different cases in ASCX and CS file.
I guess this is because .NET 2.0 is more strict with cases... Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: Another note here - .NET doesn't do a good job that I've seen of specifying which controls/variables are having a conflict. On my page I had one variable called 'bannerImage', a String, and another 'BannerImage', a PlaceHolder control and I was lucky to find the two...

Comment: You can catch this at compile time with an MS build task: http://www.onpreinit.com/2009/09/ambiguous-match-found_30.html

Comment: for example Button1 and button1, it compiles as casesensitive, but executed as caseinsensitive. what does this means? in runtime they both are same?

Comment: same name for a control and a variable on server side

Comment: This is my problem as well! Thing is, my page consists heaps of controls, textboxes etc., do you guys know a way to simplify the search?

Answer (score 13):

In your ASCX file, go through each and every control and change its id.  For example,

```
<asp:TextBox id="foo" />
```

change it to

```
<asp:TextBox id="foo1" >
```

You've probably got a control with an ID that matches a property in your ascx file, so when the compiler is trying to make instance variables its colliding.

Answer (score 2):

I've the same problem and it solved and the solution is in check your code behind and you will find a couple of Controls with the same name:

```
protected Button Home;

protected System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlAnchor home;
```

you have to erase one line or comment it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd trawl your web.config for 1.1 and 2.0 references to the same DLL. In most cases that I have gotten this it was System.Web.Extensions.

Also check the @registers in Pages if that fails.

Good luck (it is not a fun bug to find!)

Dan

Answer (score 0):

**Same Name Id in aspx file and property inside aspx.cs file**

when .aspx page and behind aspx.cs class contains Same property this kind of problem occur. When I am searching the solution for this problem.. not found any useful content. finally I solved the problem by renaming private property name to different inside aspx.cs class  attached image as screenshot.

if anyone still facing the problem you may try

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pMQY.png)
[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irnrc.png)

Answer (score -1):

This is due to what can only be described as a defect in **System.Web.UI.Util.GetNonPrivateFieldType(Type classType, String fieldName)** that allows UI (.aspx/.ascx) fields to compile as case-insensitive but attempts to retrieve them as case-sensitive during the intial parse.

A potential remedy for the time being is to catch it at compile-time with an [ms-build task](http://www.onpreinit.com/2009/09/ambiguous-match-found_30.html).